# Why is the browser not showing the HttpOnly flag sometimes?

Tags: c#, iis, razor, asp.net-ajax, asp.net-core-3.1

We have an ASP.Net Core 3.1 application with Razor pages that makes requests with AJAX and runs and IIS verson 10. There is a session cookie being set using the following code:

```
services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = ".testCookie.Session";
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
});
```

The httpOnly flag is present in the initial startup of the application.

[image]

[image]

Our security team did a check and saw that there is an issue with the httpOnly flag not showing up sometimes.

[image]

Is this something that should be expected?

The task is to make sure all the cookies have the httpOnly flag.

Comment: Have you received similar related risk warnings? - "Insecure cookie setting: missing HttpOnly flag".

Comment: No I did not, I found that there was a code to delete the cookie on refresh if it was found in the browser. Not sure why it is still being shown in the Set-Cookie when it was deleted. I also found when it is like that in the Set-Cookie, the cookie is not there under Application.

Comment: Is it possible that the Set-Cookie shell that expires the cookie could be removed from the header instead of being shown.

Comment: If your application is using a caching mechanism, responses may be cached, and you may observe cached responses with outdated Set-Cookie headers. Make sure to clear all related caches.

Comment: Your application can be tested in multiple modern browsers to ensure that the flag HttpOnly is set consistently. If you see inconsistencies, it could also be related to browser settings or extensions.